# Calculating the area between two graphs with several intersections?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, geometry

I am looking for a method to calculate the area between two graphs within a chart.  According to the picture below (for example) the area between the green and blue lines. The lines have the following properties:

- the $(x \in N, x_{1},x_{2}, ... x_{n})$ are for both lines the same
- the $(x \in R, y_{1},y_{2}, ... y_{n})$ could be diffrent (must not)
- the lines can have $(i \in N, i_{0}, i_{1}, ... ,i_{n})$ intersections

[image: line chart]

During my researching I found an interesting post on StackOverflow [[here]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439243/find-the-area-between-two-curves-plotted-in-matplotlib-fill-between-area). This post is more about implementation (in Python) and less about the maths behind, why I' am not at all happy.

In summary, I' am looking for a method that is designed for solving such a problem (f.e numerical). I think that's a basic problem that is already multiple solved with a standard procedure and algorithm. unfortunately, I did not found some well-founded references. Why I want to ask you if you know some references or are able to tell the method?

In my case, speed is more important than accuracy. So maybe exist an interesting method for approximating the area?

I really look forward to reading your answers.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: If you are satisfied with your answer, then please click the green check to close the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to do this using basic geometry and algebra, but it will be cumbersome. I believe there is an easier way, but it requires a basic knowledge of functions and calculus.

**Description of the Method**

Notice that each graph can be modeled as a piecewise function whose subfunctions are different linear functions over each unit interval in $x$. In order to determine each linear function, simply use your two endpoints over the given interval in $x$ to calculate the slope of a line that joins them, and then use the point-slope formula to determine the equation for your linear subfunction.

For example, lets determine a piecewise function for the green graph, denoted as $g(x)$. On the first interval, $0 \le x \le 1$, we have endpoints $P_1(0,75)$ and $P_2(1,100)$. We use them to compute the slope, $m$, of a line between them as follows: $m = \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = \frac{100-75}{1-0} = \frac{25}{1} = 25$. We then use the point-slope formula to get the equation of a line with slope $m$ and passing through one of the points, say $P(0,25)$, as follows: $y-y_1 = m(x-x_1) \Leftrightarrow y-75 = 25(x-0) \Leftrightarrow y=25x+75$. Hence, $g(x)=25x+75$ on the interval $0 \le x \le 1$. Repeat this process for subsequent intervals in $x$ to find each subfunction of the piecewise function $g(x)$.

Once you have defined the piecewise functions representing the all of the graphs, you can find the total area between any two graphs by computing separate integrals (one for each unit interval in $x$) between the two graphs, taking their absolute value, and then adding the results. This assumes the graphs don't intersect on a given interval. If they do intersect on an interval, then you must find the point of intersection, break that interval up into two more intervals, and then integrate over each one of those separately.

**Formal Summary**

Two arbitrary graphs $f$ and $g$ are given as piecewise functions

$$f(x) = \{ m_ix+b_i, i \le x \le i+1$$
$$g(x) = \{ m_{i+5}x+b_{i+5}, i \le x \le i+1$$

where $i \in I = \{ 0,1,2,3,4 \}$, and $m_0, m_1, m_2, ..., m_9$ and $b_0, b_1, b_2, ..., b_9$ are constant real numbers denoting the slopes and y-intercepts of each subfunction, respectively. Now, let $S = \{ x : f(x)=g(x) \}$, or in other words, $S$ is the set of x-values corresponding to all intersection points between $f$ and $g$.

Then, the total area, $A$, between $f$ and $g$ on $[0,5]$ is given by

$$A = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \biggl| \int_{m_k}^{m_{k+1}} [f(x)-g(x)] dx \biggr|$$

where $m \in M=I \cup \{5\} \cup S $, $n = |M|$, and $M$ is sorted s.t. $m_1<m_2<m_3<...<m_n$

Comment: Firstly, I want to Thank you for the detailed explanation and your spent time. So when I understood you correctly, would be the easiest way to build an equatation like this: $A = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(\int_{i}^{i+1}\left[g_{i}(x)-f_{i}(x)\right] d x\right)$ when $i$ represents the $x$ values of the coordinate system and within the sum  takes the integral between the functions $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ place. Both functions are defined over the interval $i$ and $i+1$. These functions are subfunctions of the graph and linear by segment. is that correct? kind regards

Comment: Yes, that is 100% correct. I'm actually jealous I didn't explain it as succinctly as you just did! Now, bear in mind that the algorithm you just described **does not** account for points of intersection within a given interval. If the two graphs intersect and you compute the area as described, then what you end up with is the is "net difference" in area between the two graphs and not the total area. So, anywhere the two graphs intersect, just treat that point the same as you would treat the endpoints of any one of your intervals (i.e. break up the integral into yet another interval)

Comment: Thank you for this hint! so lets me the last time clarify the equation  $A = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(\int_{i_{n}}^{i_{n+1}}\left[g_{i}(x)-f_{i}(x)\right] d x\right)$ for $i$, when $i = X \cup I$. The set $X$ contains all $x$ values of the coordinate system and $I$ is the set of points with the intersections ($x$ values of the interception point). Further the set $i$ has to be sorted $i_{n-1} < i_{n}< i_{n+1}$. Than you can just integrate about the union of $I$ and $X$.

Comment: I went ahead and updated the post to include a rigorous definition of the method I'm describing. You seem to have the right idea but the indexing seems a bit off. You also have to take the absolute value of each integral. See above and feel free to ask any follow up questions.

Comment: Thanks, just last questions...why do you introduce the variable $j$ with $m_{j}$ and $b_{j}$? I can't find them. Why do you choose the constant $5$ in $g(x) = \{ m_{i+5}x+b_{i+5}, i \le x \le i+1$ ?

Comment: I chose the constant $5$ because you have $5$ unit intervals in $x$, and I wanted to show that every $m$ and every $b$ in function $f$ is not necessarily the same $m$ and the same $b$ in function $g$. $j$ is not a variable; it is just an index to emphasize that there are a total of ten $m$'s (numbered $0-9$) between functions $f$ and $g$, and none are necessarily the same, and there are a total of ten $b$'s (numbered $0-9$) between functions $f$ and $g$, and none are necessarily the same.

Comment: Maybe this is more clear if I expand the notation... as you iterate over $I$, you build subfunctions for $f$ as follows: $m_{0}x+b_{0}$, $m_{1}x+b_{1}$, $m_{2}x+b_{2}$, $m_{3}x+b_{3}$, $m_{4}x+b_{4}$. You also build subfunctions for $g$ as follows: $m_{5}x+b_{5}$, $m_{6}x+b_{6}$, $m_{7}x+b_{7}$, $m_{8}x+b_{8}$, $m_{9}x+b_{9}$. Saying "$m_j$ for $j=0,1,2,...,9$ is a constant real number denoting the slope" is just another way of saying "$m_1, m_2, m_3,...,m_9$ are all slopes (for different subfunctions) that are not necessarily the same."

Comment: I went ahead and updated my post make it more clear

Comment: Thank you, great job! Now I understand your notation.

Answer (score 0):

You can just break it into trapezoids and triangles.

If the curves do not cross in an interval you have a trapezoid with the parallel sides vertical.  The formula is $\frac 12(b_1+b_2)h$.  Your dark green curve has points $(0,75)$ and $(1,100)$.  Your red curve has points $(0,95)$ and $(1,150)$.  The area between them is then $\frac 12((95-75)+(150-100))(1-0)=75$

If the curves do cross you have two triangles.  I assume you want both triangles counted as positive, so we need to find the crossover point.  Your blue curve has points $(1,220)$ and $(2,100)$  The orange curve has points $(1,345)$ and $(2,30)$.  We need to find the point where they intersect.  The equation of the blue graph is $y-220=(100-220)(x-1)$ and the orange graph is $y-345=(30-345)(x-1)$.  We can subtract these to get $125=195(x-1), x-1=\frac {125}{195}$.  The base of the triangle is the difference between the curves and the height is the distance from the intersection to the end of the interval, so the area are $\frac 12(345-220)\frac {125}{195}$ and $\frac 12(100-30)(1-\frac{125}{195})$